Using Javascript in TPL
How can I use JavaScript code in a TPL file to make the content of the JavaScript code appear on the page?
When I enter the code there is no error message, but nothing appears on the page either.
This is an indication of how long the site has existed.
This is the code
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
today = new Date();
bYear  = 2021;  // Start Jahr
bMonth = 4;    // Start Monat
bDay   = 7;  // Start Tag
tYear  =  today.getFullYear();
tMonth =  (today.getMonth() ) + 1 ;
tDay   =  today.getDate();
tHour  =  today.getHours();
fYear  = 0;
fMonth = 0;
fDay   = 0;
fHour  = 0;
x = 0;
y = 0;
z = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
function testMonth() {
     if (y==4 || y==6 || y==9 || y==11) x=30
     else if (y==2) x=28
     else x=31
}
function testDay() {
     fDay = (z - bDay) + tDay;
          if (fDay > a) {
               fMonth += 1;
               fDay = fDay - a;
          }
}
y = bMonth;
testMonth();
z = x;
y = bMonth;
testMonth();
a = x;
if (bMonth <= tMonth) {
     fYear = tYear - bYear;
     fMonth = (tMonth - bMonth);
     testDay();
}
fYear = (tYear - bYear) - 1
fMonth = ((12 - bMonth) + tMonth) - 1;
testDay();
if (fMonth >= 12) {
     fYear += 1;
     fMonth -= 12;
}
with(Math) {
theYear=fYear;
tensYear=floor(theYear/10);
onesYear=theYear-(tensYear*1);
theMonth=fMonth
tensMonth=floor(theMonth/10);
onesMonth=theMonth-(tensMonth*1);
theDay=fDay
tensDay=floor(theDay/10);
onesDay=theDay-(tensDay*1);
var testArray = new makeArray("Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember");
for (z=1; z<=12; z++) {
  if (tMonth==z) {
      var b=testArray[z]
   }
}
for (z=1; z<=12; z++) {
  if (bMonth==z) {
      var c=testArray[z]
   }
}
}
var page
page = "<b><center>"+tDay+". "+b+" "+tYear+".</b><br /><br></center>"
page += "<b><center>Eröffnung </b><br> "+bDay+". "+c+" "+bYear+"</center><br>"
page += "<center><b>Forum online seit...</b><br> "
if(parseInt(tensYear+onesYear) == 1) {
    page += tensYear + onesYear + " Jahr</center></b>,<b> "
}
else {
    page += tensYear + onesYear + " Jahre , "
}
if(parseInt(tensYear+onesYear) == 0) {
    page += ""
}

if(parseInt(tensMonth+onesMonth) == 1) {
    page += tensMonth + onesMonth + " Monat und "
}
else {
    page += tensMonth + onesMonth + " Monate und "
}
if(parseInt(tensDay+onesDay) == 1) {
    page += tensDay + onesDay + " Tag</b>."
}
else {
    page += tensDay + onesDay + " Tage</b>."
}
function makeArray() {
      this.length = makeArray.arguments.length
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
      this[i+1] = makeArray.arguments[i]
}
//-->
</script>

does anyone know a solution
I tried to insert it as a script into the TPL file and I tried to insert the script in {literal}{/literal}.

From the javascript tag info: "[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ..."

The javascript code it works, and it will works inside a tpl file too.
You're expecting the code to show content in the page.
For that purpose, the variable page is used to store the HTML content you want to be shown.
The variable page is filled successfully, but its content is never used.
Just add this instruction just after your code:
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//Here all your javascript code, where variable page is filled

document.write(page); //This instruction shows the content

-->
</script>  

